# How can I create a struct in JavaScript and sort it afterwards?

Tags: javascript, c#

In C#, I create a struct and I use LINQ to sort MyList.

```
public struct MyContainer
{
  public string Name;
  public string Firstname;
  public int Firstscore;
  public int Secondscore;

  public MyContainer(string name, string firstname, int firstscore, int secondscore)
  {
    Name = name;
    Firstname = firstname;
    Firstscore = firstscore;
    Secondscore = secondscore;
  }
}

public List<MyContainer> SortedList = new List<MyContainer>();
public List<MyContainer> MyList = new List<MyContainer>();

MyList.Add(new MyContainer("Kramer","Sandy",300,50);
MyList.Add(new MyContainer("Connor","Tom",450,30);
MyList.Add(new MyContainer("Black","Ron",200,55);
MyList.Add(new MyContainer("Diaz","Kate",300,40);
MyList.Add(new MyContainer("Sandler","Jessica",450,25);

SortedList = MyList.OrderBy(user => user.Firstscore).ThenBy(user => user.Secondscore).ToList();
```

I want to sort MyList first by FirstScore and then by Secondscore. SortedList should look like this after sorting MyList:

```
("Black","Ron",200,55)
("Diaz","Kate",300,40)
("Kramer","Sandy",300,50)
("Sandler","Jessica",450,25)
("Connor","Tom",450,30)
```

In C#, it works like this but I don't know how to do this in JavaScript. How can I do the same in JavaScript? How can I create a struct in JavaScript and sort it afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class with getter and setter and then sort it with custom sort function

```
function sortByFirstscoreAfterSecondscore(a, b) {
  return a.Firstscore - b.Firstscore || a.Secondscore - b.Secondscore;
}
```

```js
class MyContainer {
  constructor(Name, Firstname, Firstscore, Secondscore) {
    this._Name = Name;
    this._Firstname = Firstname;
    this._Firstscore = Firstscore;
    this._Secondscore = Secondscore;
  }

  get Firstscore() {
    return this._Firstscore;
  }

  set Fristscore(Firstscore) {
    this._Firstscore = Firstscore;
  }

  get Secondscore() {
    return this._Secondscore;
  }

  set Secondscore(Secondscore) {
    this._Secondscore = Secondscore;
  }
}

let list = [];
list.push(new MyContainer("Kramer", "Sandy", 300, 50));
list.push(new MyContainer("Connor", "Tom", 450, 30));
list.push(new MyContainer("Black", "Ron", 200, 55));
list.push(new MyContainer("Diaz", "Kate", 300, 40));
list.push(new MyContainer("Sandler", "Jessica", 450, 25));


function sortByFirstscoreAfterSecondscore(a, b) {
  return a.Firstscore - b.Firstscore || a.Secondscore - b.Secondscore;
}

const result = [...list].sort(sortByFirstscoreAfterSecondscore);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const arr = [
    { name:"Sandler", firstname: "Jessica", firstscore: 450, secondscore: 25 },
    { name:"Diaz", firstname: "Kate", firstscore: 300, secondscore: 50 },
    { name:"Black", firstname: "Ron", firstscore: 200, secondscore: 51 },
    { name:"Connor", firstname: "Tom", firstscore: 200, secondscore: 55 },
  ]
  console.log(`arr`, arr);
  
  arr.sort((a,b)=>a.firstscore-b.firstscore || a.secondscore-b.secondscore )
  console.log(`arr`, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For MyContainer, you could do a class:

```
class MyContainer {
  constructor(name, firstname, firstscore, secondscore) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.firstscore = firstscore;
    this.secondscore = secondscore;
  }
}

const example = new MyContainer('Kramer', 'sandy', 300, 50);
```

Though for something as simple as this, you can also consider just doing object literals:

```
const example = { 
  name: 'kramer',
  firstname: 'sandy',
  firstscore: 300,
  secondscore: 50,
}
```

You'll then put these into an array, and use the array's `.sort` method to sort it. You provide a function to sort telling it how to compare items. Returning a positive number says to put element `b` first; negative number puts `a` first; 0 leaves them in the same order.

```js
class MyContainer {
  constructor(name, firstname, firstscore, secondscore) {
    this.name = name;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.firstscore = firstscore;
    this.secondscore = secondscore;
  }
}

const myList = [
  new MyContainer("Kramer", "Sandy", 300, 50),
  new MyContainer("Connor", "Tom", 450, 30),
  new MyContainer("Black", "Ron", 200, 55),
  new MyContainer("Diaz", "Kate", 300, 40),
  new MyContainer("Sandler", "Jessica", 450, 25),
];

const sortedList = [...myList]; // create a shallow copy
sortedList.sort((a, b) => {
  const firstScoreDiff = a.firstscore - b.firstscore;
  if (firstScoreDiff === 0) {
    return a.secondscore - b.secondscore;
  } else {
    return firstScoreDiff;
  }
});

console.log(sortedList);
```

Comment: The list is not sorted correctly. With your code, it is sorted like this:  Black, Kramer, Diaz, Connor, Sandler. But it should be: Black, Diaz, Kramer, Sandler, Connor. When two people have an identical firstscore, then the person with the lowest secondscore should be first in the sortedList. But with your code, it's reversed.

Comment: Then swap the order. Instead of a - b, do b -a.

Comment: I changed the line return a.secondScore - b.secondscore; to return b.secondScore - a.secondscore; but it is still not working.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, where i spelled it `secondScore` with an uppercase S. Did you change that to `secondscore`?

Comment: Thanx. That was the problem. It works now.